# Moving objects inside the collection (Layers panel)?

Tags: collections

Is it possible to move objects inside this objects panel/Scene collection? I have now a Camera as a 1st object, 2nd is Cylinder and 3rd is Cube, but I want to arrange them differently. Is that possible? Or do I have to create first a Collection for each of the objects?

Comment: AFAIK that's not possible. It sorts alphabetically. You could rename your objects...

Answer (score 1):

Use symbols in front of object names to move them up or down Cube - _Cube would be first. Also, you could try Parenting to change the order.

Answer (score 0):

In 2.9 and later it is somewhat possible, but it is difficult.

First, you have to disable "Sort Alphabetically":

[image: Filter menu showing Sort Alphabetically Option]

Then there is no way to drag objects around within a collection.  So you have to remove objects from the collection and return them, knowing that each object added to a collection is added to the *front* of the collection list.

Comment: Slightly simpler, but still annoying - you can Shift-D the object (it appends to the collection at the end) and then delete the original one.